# nvidia-smi No devices were found on KVM VM

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-geforce

```
OS - Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
RAM - 8GB 
GPU - Nvidia GeForce GTX 1050Ti 
Laptop - Acer Predator Helio 300 
Secure Boot - Disabled
```

I followed [KVM : GPU Passthrough](https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Ubuntu_18.04&p=kvm&f=11) guide to launch VM that should use GPU.

**Updated grub config**

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="intel_iommu=on iommu=pt rd.driver.pre=vfio-pci video=efifb:off"
```

**Added VFIO modules**

```
veeru@ghost:~$ cat /etc/initram-fs/modules
vfio
vfio_iommu_type1
vfio_pci
vfio_virqfd

veeru@ghost:~$ lspci -nn | grep -i nvidia 
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile] [10de:1c8c] (rev a1)

veeru@ghost:~$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/vfio.conf 
options vfio-pci ids=10de:1c8c
options vfio-pci disable_vga=1
```

**After reboot I verified IOMMU is enabled by running below commands**

```
veeru@ghost:~$ dmesg | grep -E "DMAR|IOMMU" 
[    0.000000] ACPI: DMAR 0x0000000089CEB000 0000A8 (v01 ACRSYS ACRPRDCT 00000002 1025 00040000)
[    0.000000] DMAR: IOMMU enabled
[    0.004000] DMAR: Host address width 39
[    0.004000] DMAR: DRHD base: 0x000000fed90000 flags: 0x0
---- OUTPUT REMOVED -------

veeru@ghost:~$ dmesg | grep -i vfio
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-42-generic root=UUID=d4aa9af4-beb0-4da2-969c-3e41e01f335b ro intel_iommu=on iommu=pt rd.driver.pre=vfio-pci video=efifb:off quiet splash vt.handoff=1
---- OUTPUT REMOVED -----
```

Switched `X` to use Intel CPU

[image]

Started VM with `virt-install` and installed OS

```
sudo virt-install \
--name vm1 \
--memory 2028 \
--disk path=/home/veeru/ubuntu14-HD.img,size=30 \
--vcpus 2 \
--os-type linux \
--os-variant ubuntu16.04 \
--network bridge=virbr0 \
--graphics none \
--console pty,target_type=serial \
--location /home/veeru/Downloads/ubuntu-16.04.5.iso --force \
--extra-args 'console=ttyS0,115200n8 serial' \
--host-device 01:00.0 \
--features kvm_hidden=on \
--machine q35
```

After login to VM, I installed nvidia drivers with `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` and did `apt update && apt upgrade`.

**Inside VM, I'm able run below commands and check outputs**

```
veeru@ubuntu:~$ lspci | grep -i nvidia
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1c8c (rev a1)

veeru@ubuntu:~$ lsmod | grep -i nvidia
nvidia_uvm            675840  0
nvidia_drm             49152  0
nvidia_modeset        860160  1 nvidia_drm
nvidia              13164544  2 nvidia_modeset,nvidia_uvm
drm_kms_helper        155648  1 nvidia_drm
drm                   364544  3 drm_kms_helper,nvidia_drm

veeru@ubuntu:~$ ls -l /dev/nvidia* 
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 195,   0 Dec 13 02:33 /dev/nvidia0
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 195, 255 Dec 13 02:33 /dev/nvidiactl
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 246,   0 Dec 13 02:33 /dev/nvidia-uvm
```

**But it looks like VM is not using GPU**

```
veeru@ubuntu:~$ nvidia-smi
No devices were found
```

I see some similar issue and mailing list like

https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/847649/cuda-setup-and-installation/nvidia-smi-quot-no-devices-were-found-quot-error-/

https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-virtualization/2017-January/005119.html

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: It's obviously there. Maybe nvidia-smi is not the correct tool to use. Why don't you try just using it? What's your use case?

Comment: @HackSlash Well I want to run kubernetes on the VM i.e. the containers should use GPU

Comment: Right, but what is the application? What is actually using the GPU? Can you just run it? Test it?